# RoboGuice.getInjector throws an Exception

Tags: android, roboguice

I try to start using RoboGuice 2 in my android project and it works ok unless I try to use it to inject views in activities. If I try to extend my activity from RoboActivity or manually call RoboGuice.getInjector(context) in onCreate method, I get the following exception:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity}: com.google.inject.ConfigurationException: Guice configuration errors:
    1) Could not find a suitable constructor in roboguice.inject.ContextScope. Classes must have either one (and only one) constructor annotated with @Inject or a zero-argument constructor that is not private.
            at roboguice.inject.ContextScope.class(Unknown Source)
    while locating roboguice.inject.ContextScope
    1 error
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: com.google.inject.ConfigurationException: Guice configuration errors:
    1) Could not find a suitable constructor in roboguice.inject.ContextScope. Classes must have either one (and only one) constructor annotated with @Inject or a zero-argument constructor that is not private.
            at roboguice.inject.ContextScope.class(Unknown Source)
    while locating roboguice.inject.ContextScope
    1 error
            at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:1004)
            at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:961)
            at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1013)
            at roboguice.inject.ContextScopedRoboInjector.<init>(ContextScopedRoboInjector.java:27)
            at roboguice.RoboGuice.getInjector(RoboGuice.java:149)
            ...
```

I use maven to add the guice to my project using the following dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.roboguice</groupId>
  <artifactId>roboguice</artifactId>
  <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

By default RoboGuice will try to create the object using the default constructor. It seems your object doesn't have a default constructor.
You can work around this by:

- annotating the constructor you want to use with `@Inject` (and make sure all the parameters of that constructor can be created by RoboGuice as well)
- create a default constructor in the object you are trying to inject
- if you don't have control over the object you are trying to inject, you can use a provider to construct the object during the injection phase

Answer (score 0):

I found out that if I simply extend AbstractModule it requires much more efforts to properly configure than just simply bind context.

I extended the DefaultRoboModule as explained in javadoc:

```
Injector injector =
    RoboGuice.setBaseApplicationInjector(
        this, Stage.PRODUCTION,
        Modules.override(RoboGuice.newDefaultRoboModule(this)).with(new MyModule())
    );
```

and got everything working as expected.

Thanks anyway.